# como posso resolver este erro em python unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

```
#Validador de notas v1.1 (BETA)
import time

print('[            +            ]')

NomeAluno = (input('Digite o nome do aluno >> '))

Nota1 = print('Digite a primeira nota.') 
float(input('Nota 1 >> '))
Nota2 = print('Digite a segunda nota.')
float(input('Nota 2 >> '))
Nota3 = print('Digite a terceira nota.')
float(input('Nota 3 >> '))
MediaAluno = Nota1 + Nota2 + Nota3 / 3

if MediaAluno == MediaAluno >= 6:
    time.sleep (4)
    print('O(a) aluno {} Tem a média de {}, ele(a) está aprovado(a) <<✔️>>'.format(NomeAluno, MediaAluno))
else:
    print('O(a) aluno {} Tem a média de {}, ele(a) está precisando de nota ou está reprovado(a). . .'.format(NomeAluno, MediaAluno))

print('[            +            ]')
```

Answer (score -2):

Considere rever o conceito de variáveis [em python](https://youtu.be/hdDHg1p3YVc?si=N0SWy5aNJjR0tcQf). Além disso, `print` é uma função de saída.
Segue a solução:

```
import time

print('[ + ]')

NomeAluno = (input('Digite o nome do aluno >> '))

print('Digite a primeira nota.')
Nota1 = float(input('Nota 1 >> '))

print('Digite a segunda nota.') 
Nota2 = float(input('Nota 2 >> '))

print('Digite a terceira nota.')
Nota3 = float(input('Nota 3 >> '))
MediaAluno = Nota1 + Nota2 + Nota3 / 3

if MediaAluno == MediaAluno >= 6:
    time.sleep (4)
    print('O(a) aluno {} Tem a média de {}, ele(a) está aprovado(a) <<✔️>>'.format(NomeAluno, MediaAluno))

else:
    print('O(a) aluno {} Tem a média de {}, ele(a) está precisando de nota ou está reprovado(a). . .'.format(NomeAluno, MediaAluno))

print('[ + ]')
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).